# Importing python classes, relative to where?

Tags: python, module, include

If I have a small python project split into a main directory with 2 subdirs:

```
src/
    run.py
    subdir1/
            __init__.py
            module1.py
            subdir2/
                    __init__.py
                    module2.py
```

In order to include module2 in module1 would I have to use the full include path: `from subdir1.subdir2.module2 import Class2` (relative to the python file that is being run), or could I use `from subdir2.module2 import Class2`? (relative to the file that statement is in)

```
src/
    run.py
    subdir1/
            __init__.py
            module1.py
    subdir2/
            __init__.py
            module2.py
```

How is it now best to include module2 in module1, I have tried relative to where the program is run, i.e. `from subdir2.module2 import Class2` but this gives the error `"No module named module2"` I cant help thinking this is not the most portable way of doing things anyhow, would it not be better with a path relative to the file where the statement exists, especcially in the 1st example.

I'm assuming it wont mess things up if I call the code from another active directory, or will it? `python dir/run.py`

Thanks!

Comment: Which python version are you on?

Comment: 2.7 but im interested in knowing the answer for 3 too if someone has a source :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to import module:

1. absolute import
2. relative import

Absolute import makes python to look for desired module in directories stored in `sys.path`
Relative import address to module relative to current module. You can use relative import inside python packages only.

for first case You can use relative import because `subdir1` is a package

for the second one You can't use relative import because `subdir1` and `subdir2` are not in package.

according to pep-8:

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a directory inside a package ends up on sys.path):

```
import mypkg.sibling
from mypkg import sibling
from mypkg.sibling import example
```

> However, explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports, especially when dealing with complex package layouts where using absolute imports would be unnecessarily verbose:

```
from . import sibling
from .sibling import example
```

> Standard library code should avoid complex package layouts and always use absolute imports.
>
> Implicit relative imports should never be used and have been removed in Python 3.

Comment: also how does python tell the difference between a relative and an absolute filepath? what if I have a module named sibling inside the root of the project and in the module dir that is including the latter sibling with a relative path; which will it choose?

Comment: explicit relative import starts with `.`. And Implicit relative import is depricated. But as I remember in python 2.7 relative implicit import will be tried before absolute one

Comment: ok so in this case: "from .sibling import example" sibling is not a sibling, its a child/subdir?

Comment: no `from .sibling import example` means from module `sibling` which is  in the same package with me import `example`

Comment: What do i do wrong if i get 'ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package' ?

Comment: for the second one You can't use relative import because subdir1 and subdir2 are not in package.

Comment: and what should than be in the init files?